# How To Redirect www to Non-www with path url complete in apache2

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, hosting

All paths with www ([www.example.com/posts/categories](http://www.example.com/posts/categories)) redirect to the home page. How can i redirect from .htaccess and keep the full path?

```
https://www.example.com/posts/categories to https://example.com/posts/categories
```

current configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: The rule you've posted would already do this. You may have a conflict with other directives. Please update your question to include your complete `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

You've put this rule in the wrong place. It needs to go at the start, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive. By placing it at the end, after the rewrite to `index.php`, any request for the www subdomain will be redirected to `index.php` (during the second round of processing).

As a general rule, external redirects should always go before internal rewrites.

You should also consider implementing an HTTP to HTTPS redirect.